# Can I use Moment.js to fix a client side date format issue?

Tags: 8, datetime

Different Browser and OS show a different date format on client side. Given the following markup:

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-field-date-end-value-date" title="Date (e.g. 2019-05-15)" type="date" min="1969-05-15" max="2069-05-15" data-drupal-date-format="Y-m-d" id="edit-field-date-end-value-date" name="field_date[end_value][date]" value="2019-05-11" size="12" class="form-date hasDatepicker">
```

- In Chrome: dd/mm/yyyy
- In Safari: yyyy-mm-dd

I think it's an issue with input type date, because it is showing as per browsers HTML5 or HTML4.

How can I solve this issue? So while load or if select from datepicker then it also solves? Do I maybe need to use Moment.js?

http://jsfiddle.net/g7mvaosL/

Answer (score -2):

Actually the thing is `type="date"` is not supported by the Safari browser and moreover best practice is to use server time rather using JavaScript. Maybe the following code helps

```
var dateSTR = "2019-05-15";

var date = new Date(dateSTR.replace(/-/g,"/"));

console.log("0:" + new Date("2019-05-15"))
console.log("1:" + date)
date.setUTCHours(date.getHours());
console.log("2:" + date)
date.setUTCMinutes(date.getMinutes());
console.log("3:" + date);
console.log("4:" + date.toLocaleDateString());
```